# gnuplot plotting multiple line graphs

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following dat file, named `ls.dat`:

```
# Gnuplot script file for "ls"
# Version       Removed Added   Modified
8.1     0       0       0
8.4     0       0       4
8.5     2       5       9
8.6     2       7       51
8.7     2       7       51
8.8     2       7       51
8.9     2       7       51
8.10    2       7       51
8.11    2       8       112
8.12    2       8       112
8.13    2       17      175
8.17    6       33      213
```

I am trying to plot with this:

```
plot "ls.dat" using 1:2 title 'Removed' with lines,\
     "ls.dat" using 1:3 title 'Added' with lines,\
     "ls.dat" using 1:4 title 'Modified' with lines
```

This produces the following graph:

[image]

What I am expecting is three line plots which should all go up, but at different rates. Can anyone see what is going on here? I'm sure it must be something very silly.

Comment: How did you get this Gnuplot GUI?  What command launches this window?

Comment: @Jeef Its gnuplot-X11 in OSX. You can also use gnuplot in Qt. It depends where is your terminal type set to what you get. Mine is gnuplot-qt.

Comment: Thanks - this was so long ago i forgot what i even was doing!  :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think your problem is your version numbers.  Try making 8.1 --> 8.01, and so forth.  That should put the points in the right order.

Alternatively, you could plot `using X`, where X is the column number you want, instead of `using 1:X`.  That will plot those values on the y axis and integers on the x axis.  Try:

```
plot "ls.dat" using 2 title 'Removed' with lines, \
     "ls.dat" using 3 title 'Added' with lines, \
     "ls.dat" using 4 title 'Modified' with lines
```

Comment: You may also want a log scale on the y axis (using `set log y`) since your numbers span such a range.

Comment: Good point on the `using X` -- I think that you could also use `using X:xtic(1)` to keep your xtics the version number that you want, though I haven't tried it...(+1)

Comment: Also, andyras, you're putting a real damper on my quest to get the bronze gnuplot badge by answering all these questions before I get a chance to see them ;) .

Answer (score 11):

andyras is completely correct.  One minor addition, try this (for example)

```
plot 'ls.dat' using 4:xtic(1)
```

This will keep your datafile in the correct order, but also preserve your version tic labels on the x-axis.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the answers above the command below will also work. I post it because it makes more sense to me. In each case it is 'using x-value-column: y-value-column'

```
plot 'ls.dat' using 1:2, 'ls.dat' using 1:3, 'ls.dat' using 1:4
```

note that the command above assumes that you have a file named `ls.dat` with tab separated columns of data where column 1 is x, column 2 is y1, column 3 is y2 and column 4 is y3.

**Edit for `.csv` file types....**

Note if you have a `.csv` file then if you use the gnuplot command

```
set datafile separator comma
```

you can then use the plot command above for data files where the numbers are separated by commas.

Comment: Hi, tom. What's the version of your gnuplot?

Comment: @ScottYang when I wrote the answer the version might have been 4.2, but I am really not sure to be honest. I think any version of Gnuplot should work with the command above as I think it has been pretty standard for a while. I just used it to plot a data file with Gnuplot 5.0n --- plus note that I have put an edit in the answer as well to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your separator is in your *ls.dat*, you can specify it to **gnuplot**:

```
set datafile separator "\t"
```